# aframe splitscreen to single screen effect

Tags: javascript, aframe

Hey there dearest reader,

is there a way to show the same picture/ video on two or even more flat objects (i.e. Triangle, rectangle, circle, ect.)?
Sounds easy enough, but I mean with a splitscreen to single screen effect like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fDPYhzui1IE/maxresdefault.jpg) for example.
The simplest way is probably splitting the content, aye? So maybe a javascript video editor? Found nothing really satisfying so far,  but maybe I am just searching with an unclear imagination of what I want. Therefor any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks & Greetings
Orys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there dearest OP.

If you can't fake it (having a big plane with the image + overlay a cross), then I'd try with using shaders.

A custom shader which will use the "top" or "bottom" side of the image could look like this:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // register a custom component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    // we wanna pass a value "top" or "bottom"
    schema: {
      side: {
        value: "top"
      }
    },
    init: function() {

      // vertex shader. we only want it to pass the UV to the frag shader
      const vertexShader = `
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
            vUv = uv;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                          modelViewMatrix *
                          vec4(position,1.0);
          }
        `;

      const fragmentShader = `
            uniform bool top;
            uniform sampler2D map; 
            varying vec2 vUv;           
                
            void main() {
                // the top one is 1 - .5
                // the bottom one .5 - 0
                
                vec2 coords = vUv.xy;
                coords.y = coords.y / 2.0; // stretch half of it.
                if (top) {
                    coords.y += 0.5; // if top - apply offset
                }
                                
                vec4 mapTexel = texture2D( map, coords );
                gl_FragColor = mapTexel;
            }
        `
      // wait until the entity is loaded
      this.el.addEventListener("loaded", e => {
        // grab the mesh
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
        // load the texture
        const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpeg');
        // create a new shadermaterial with the defined shaders
        const newMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
          uniforms: {
            top: {
              type: "b",
              value: this.data.side === "top" ? true : false
            },
            map: {
              type: "t",
              value: texture
            }
          },
          vertexShader: vertexShader,
          fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
          transparent: true
        });

        // apply the new material - get rid of the old one
        const oldMaterial = mesh.material;
        mesh.material = newMaterial
        mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;

        oldMaterial.dispose();
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>

  <a-plane width="2" position="0 2.25 -3" foo="side: top"></a-plane>
  <a-plane width="2" position="0 1 -3" foo="side: bottom"></a-plane>

  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Trying to get it work with video as source and more complex geometrical forms, but since I am a beginner this will take me a while and for starters I have to learn more about threejs and shaders I guess. :) May I use your example as a starting point for my journey? I can keep you updated if you like.

Comment: Glad i could help, I can try and make an example where a video is used